# The Great Tag Wiki Cleanup of 2012 and early 2013

Tags: discussion, tags

In a recent discussion regarding [What's the difference between the tools tag and the pm-software tag?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/whats-the-difference-between-the-tools-tag-and-the-pm-software-tag) as well as this question about [Revisiting Tool Recommendation Questions](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/revisiting-tool-recommendation-questions), we've come to the conclusion that we need a tag wiki cleanup.

By ensuring that our tags have proper tag wikis, we can then more clearly focus on ideas such as whether or not tag X is really needed or if tag A and B can be merged together.

Here is some important information from one of our community managers on the subject, [A Note on Tag Wiki Excerpts](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/a-note-on-tag-wiki-excerpts):

> Tag wikis are about *why* you would use a tag. Tag wikis are not to define the term being used. Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.
>
> This tag wiki except doesn't work…
>
> > **Resume**
> >
> > A résumé is a list of credentials given to a prospective employer that clearly lays out your education, skills and abilities.
>
> This is better…
>
> > **Career Development**
> >
> > For questions about advancing one's career as a whole rather than working in a specific job function or company.

For those of you new to tag wikis, there are two parts, an excerpt and a full tag wiki. Use the excerpt, as outlined above, to make it clear when a tag should be used. Use the full tag wiki to go into full details such as defining the topic, including some great example questions, links for learning more on the subject, and information about how to get started learning the topic.

At this time, we're looking to mainly improve just the excerpts, but if you want to improve the full tag wiki, go for it.

Lastly, unlike edits to questions and answers, edits to tag wikis are put into the suggested edits queue for everyone except [trusted users](https://pm.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user).  If you're approving a tag wiki, which you can do in the Suggested Edit Review Queue as a [1500+ rep user](https://pm.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), I encourage you to Google the content and reject -- and improve -- anything that is plagiarized. For instance, [I googled one of our tag wikis and found the content in the search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Technical+Debt+(also+known+as+design+debt+or+code+debt)+is+a+term+coined+by+Ward+Cunningham+to+describe+the+cumulative+consequences+of+corners+being+cut+throughout+a+software+project%E2%80%99s+design+and+development.+The+basic+idea+is+that+a+development+team%2C+over+time%2C+cuts+corners+due+to+lack+of+skill%2C+laziness+or+pressure%2C+which+then+manifests+itself+as+a+large+backlog+of+technical+inefficiencies+that+needs+%22paying+off%22+in+the+future.+Technical+debt+encompasses+issues+related+to+the+code+base%2C+development+environment%2C+platform+and+libraries%2C+architecture+and+design%2C+and+test+automation%2C+among+others.+The+impact+on+the+project+includes+reduced+velocity%2C+recruiting+difficulties%2C+and+high+defect+rates.&oq=Technical+Debt+(also+known+as+design+debt+or+code+debt)+is+a+term+coined+by+Ward+Cunningham+to+describe+the+cumulative+consequences+of+corners+being+cut+throughout+a+software+project%E2%80%99s+design+and+development.+The+basic+idea+is+that+a+development+team%2C+over+time%2C+cuts+corners+due+to+lack+of+skill%2C+laziness+or+pressure%2C+which+then+manifests+itself+as+a+large+backlog+of+technical+inefficiencies+that+needs+%22paying+off%22+in+the+future.+Technical+debt+encompasses+issues+related+to+the+code+base%2C+development+environment%2C+platform+and+libraries%2C+architecture+and+design%2C+and+test+automation%2C+among+others.+The+impact+on+the+project+includes+reduced+velocity%2C+recruiting+difficulties%2C+and+high+defect+rates.&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Feel free to begin, and if you find anything that warrants discussion, please bring it here to meta.

Comment: @AzizShaikh - Sorry, that's not really how I meant it to come off, but it's a pretty common issue so I felt I had to mention it. I had an edit reversed on another site recently, and the reason was plagiarism, so it happens to the best of us and I know the feeling. ;)

Comment: I understand. I think its good that you explicitly mentioned it in your post.